# Limiting the number of threadpool threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

I am using [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) in my application. I have first set the limit of the thread pool by using the following:

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(m_iThreadPoolLimit,m_iThreadPoolLimit);
m_Events = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

and then I have queued up the jobs using the following

```
WaitCallback objWcb = new WaitCallback(abc);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(objWcb, m_objThreadData);
```

Here abc is the name of the function that I am calling.
After this I am doing the following so that all my threads come to 1 point and the main thread takes over and continues further

```
m_Events.WaitOne();
```

My thread limit is 3. The problem that I am facing is, inspite of the thread pool limit set to 3, my application is processing more than 3 files at the same time, whereas it was supposed to process only 3 files at a time. Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: You should check `SetMaxThreads()`'s return value.

Comment: Unless you know what you're doing it's better not to mess around with the number of threads in the ThreadPool. Let the runtime handle it. If you need to limit the number of files being accessed concurrently find a better way - like using a semaphore.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't allow you to set max threads < CPU cores. I need cores-1 thread. 1 core to ramain to OS.

Answer (score 5):

What kind of computer are you using?

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx)

> You cannot set the number of worker
>   threads or the number of I/O
>   completion threads to a number smaller
>   than the number of processors in the
>   computer.

If you have 4 cores, then the smallest you can have is 4.

Also note:

> If the common language runtime is
>   hosted, for example by Internet
>   Information Services (IIS) or SQL
>   Server, the host can limit or prevent
>   changes to the thread pool size.

If this is a web site hosted by IIS then you cannot change the thread pool size either.

Comment: Yes i have tried setting 1 argument of set max thread to 0, still not working.

Comment: @Sanchaita You cannot set the number of worker threads to 0.  You have to set it to a number greater than the number of processors of the computer (everybody has at least 1).  If you have a Quad Core then you need to set it at at least 4.  On my I7 windows 7 thinks I have 8 cores.  The number would have to be at least 8.

Answer (score 4):

A better solution involves the use of a `Semaphore` which can throttle the concurrent access to a resource<sup>1</sup>. In your case the resource would simply be a block of code that processes work items.

```
var finished = new CountdownEvent(1); // Used to wait for the completion of all work items.
var throttle = new Semaphore(3, 3); // Used to throttle the processing of work items.
foreach (WorkItem item in workitems)
{
  finished.AddCount();
  WorkItem capture = item; // Needed to safely capture the loop variable.
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    (state) =>
    {
      throttle.WaitOne();
      try
      {
        ProcessWorkItem(capture);
      }
      finally
      {
        throttle.Release();
        finished.Signal();
      }
    }, null);
}
finished.Signal();
finished.Wait();
```

In the code above `WorkItem` is a hypothetical class that encapsulates the specific parameters needed to process your tasks.

The [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) makes this pattern a lot easier. Just use the `Parallel.ForEach` method and specify a `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreesOfParallelism` that throttles the concurrency.

```
var options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3;
Parallel.ForEach(workitems, options,
  (item) =>
  {
    ProcessWorkItem(item);
  });
```

---

<sup>1</sup>I should point out that I do not like blocking `ThreadPool` threads using a `Semaphore` or any blocking device. It basically wastes the threads. You might want to rethink your design entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Semaphore object to limit concurent threads.

Answer (score 1):

You say the files are open: are they actually being actively processed, or just left open?
If you're leaving them open: Been there, done that! Relying on connections and resources (it was a DB connection in my case) to close at end of scope should work, but it can take for the dispose / garbage collection to kick in.