# C# Multi-Threading - Limiting the amount of concurrent threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have question on controlling the amount of concurrent threads I want running. Let me explain with what I currently do: For example

```
 var myItems = getItems(); // is just some generic list

 // cycle through the mails, picking 10 at a time
 int index = 0;
 int itemsToTake = myItems.Count >= 10 ? 10 : myItems.Count;
 while (index < myItems.Count)
 {
     var itemRange = myItems.GetRange(index, itemsToTake);
     AutoResetEvent[] handles = new AutoResetEvent[itemsToTake];

     for (int i = 0; i < itemRange.Count; i++)
     {
         var item = itemRange[i];
         handles[i] = new AutoResetEvent(false);

         // set up the thread
         ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(processItems, new Item_Thread(handles[i], item));
     }

    // wait for all the threads to finish
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles);

    // update the index
    index += itemsToTake;
    // make sure that the next batch of items to get is within range
    itemsToTake = (itemsToTake + index < myItems.Count) ? itemsToTake : myItems.Count -index;
```

This is a path that I currently take. However I do not like it at all. I know I can 'manage' the thread pool itself, but I have heard it is not advisable to do so. So what is the alternative? The semaphore class?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?  For example - do you want to limit the number of threads you can create - if so why - and what do you want to happen if you try to create more?  Do you want to limit the number of threads that run concurrently - if so it's already limited to the number of cores.

Comment: Set the maximum number of threads available in the ThreadPool?

Comment: Yep sorry. Got a trigger finger. Updated now :)

Comment: Did you read this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017918/limiting-the-number-of-threadpool-threads

Comment: Why do you want to limit the number of threads running these tasks? You'll almost always pick the wrong limit (e.g. 10) if you tune it by hand. Have you looked at more modern approaches such as the TPL?

Comment: Very difficult to know the correct approach to threading without knowing what processItems does.

Comment: processItems primarily makes database calls.

Comment: Ok, so question is does it really benefit from parallel processing? Does each thread lock the database tables anyway? How many cores do you have and how many are free?  If it's just straightforward processing splitting it up into lots of threads will just slow things down.  If the threads were making calls to remote web services or something else which made them site idle, or if your running on some 16/32+ core beast then that's a different matter.  You need to decide a) is threading worth while, b) what's the maximum number of worthwhile threads (in your case this will be a small number).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Has made things more clear. Anyway no it should not lock the tables, and I think the server has 8 cores, could be wrong. Not sure on how many are available at any given time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use THE treadpool, get another one (just look for google, there are half a dozen implementations out) and manage that yourself.

Managing THE treadpool is not advisable as a lot of internal workings may go ther, managing your OWN threadpool instance is totally ok.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `ThreadPool` directly, you might also consider using TPL or PLINQ. For example, with PLINQ you could do something like this:

```
getItems().AsParallel()
          .WithDegreeOfParallelism(numberOfThreadsYouWant)
          .ForAll(item => process(item));
```

or using `Parallel`:

```
var options = new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = numberOfThreadsYouWant};
Parallel.ForEach(getItems, options, item => process(item));
```

Make sure that specifying the degree of parallelism does actually improve performance of your application. TPL and PLINQ use ThreadPool by default, which does a very good job of managing the number of threads that are running. In .NET 4, ThreadPool implements algorithms that add more processing threads only if that improves performance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does 'WithDegreeOfParallelism' just use 'SetMaxThreads' method of thread pool under the hood?

Comment: No, that would mean limiting the number of threads available in the ThreadPool for the entire application. Degree of parallelism controls how many processors (or cores) are used to run the processing. You can read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can control the maximum number of threads using [ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx), although I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the question is; "How do I limit the number of worker threads?" The the answer would be use a producer-consumer queue where you control the number of worker threads. Just queue your items and let it handle workers.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826981/how-to-reuse-threads-in-net-3-5/5828863#5828863) is a generic implementation you could use.

Comment: Yes, I wrote it. You should be able to give it an Action<T> to process your items when dequeued, then Enqueue your items. Give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads Method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.threading.threadpool_members%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), there is a mention of `SetMaxThreads` ...

```
public static bool SetMaxThreads (
int workerThreads,
int completionPortThreads
)
```

> Sets the number of requests to the thread pool that can be active concurrently. All requests above that number remain queued until thread pool threads become available.

However:

> You cannot set the number of worker threads or the number of I/O completion threads to a number smaller than the number of processors in the computer.

But I guess you are anyways better served by using a non-singleton thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to deal with hybrid thread synchronization constructs (such is AutoResetEvent) and the ThreadPool.

You can use a class that can act as the coordinator responsible for executing all of your code asynchronously.

Wrap using a Task or the APM pattern what the "Item_Thread" does. Then use the **AsyncCoordinator** class by Jeffrey Richter (can be found at the code from the book CLR via C# 3rd Edition).